# How would you structure mutual rating social network model on Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I think it would be easier to display my model with an example. The functionality of the app would be the following: It would be social network schema. A mutual friend model. When a user logins in the app, a list will be displayed. Each list item consist of a friend `name` - `photos`(photo1, photo2) - `rating` for each photo(calculated based on both ratings).

Example:
Logged in as UserA:

```
list item1:
[
 name: UserBName,
 photo1: 5 (UserA rated it 2, UserB rated it 8),
 photo2: 4 (UserA rated it 3, UserB rated it 5)
],
list item2:
[
 name: UserCName, 
 photo1: 2 (UserA rated it 1, UserC rated it 4)
]
```

I was thinking of creating a friend subcollection for each user document and inside having a structure like that:

```
UserB: {
     name: UserBName,
     photo1:{
      rating from UserA: 4
      rating from UserB: 2
     },
     photo2:{
      rating from UserA: 3
      rating from UserB: 5
     }
    }
```

My issue is that UserB(document)->friends(subcollection)->UserA(document) would have the same data and i am not so sure if its a viable solution.

Comment: *i am not so sure if its a viable solution* - so what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicating data and denormalizing data is common practice in NoSQL databases. It's used to flatten structures so queries can be run against the data. In the question we don't know what kind of queries you want to run other than

> When a user logins in the app, a list will be displayed. Each list
>   item consist of a friend name - photos(photo1, photo2) - rating for
>   each photo(calculated based on both ratings).

Which doesn't require a query. Using the structure in the question, when UserB logs in, your app will read the UserB document which will contain their name and all of their photo's and ratings so all of that data will be available as soon as the document is read.

However...

If each user has LOTS of photos's that could be a LOT of data to be read in and could overwhelm the device. Additionally, if you are really trying to avoid duplicating data, then you need to put the data in one place.

I would change the structure completely to provide more flexibility in only reading in the data you want.

First a simpler user collection: the documentId's are the users uid and then store their name etc as field within each document

```
users
   uid_0:
      name:
   uid_1:
      name:
```

Then a photos collection that stores the ratings

```
firestore_root
   photos
      photo_0
         uid_0: 4
         uid_1: 2
      photo_1
         uid_3: 2
         uid_2: 5
      photo_2
         uid_0: 3
         uid_1: 1
```

So then when a user logs in, perform a query on the photo's node for all photos that contain a users uid with a rating > -1  (assuming ratings go from 0 to 5 for example). In this case that would be photo_0 and photo_2

in pseudo-code, to get all of the nodes that uid_1 has rated

```
queryPhotos() {
    photoCollection.whereField("uid_1", isGreaterThan: -1).getDocuments() { querySnapshot, error in
        //the snapshot will contain photo_0 and photo_2
        for doc in querySnapshot.documents { //iterate over each photo
            //you'll have all of the fields here and can calculate an average rating
            print(doc.documentID, doc.data())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that UserA is able to rate photo1 differently for his friends as i showed in my example. So in the photos collection i would need to check both users uid. On the other hand if i duplicate the data like i showed in my example as you said i would just read the data. Anyway i am not trying to avoid duplicating the data in case it covers my app needs. So i guess i should stick with initial idea. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexChar *I would need to check both users uid* No, you won't need to do that. It doesn't matter *what* UserA rates a photo, just that they did, as the query will return ALL photos that UserA rated and you can do your calculation based on the ratings in the photo's child nodes. I would not suggest using your inital idea - this solution is much more scaleable and will require far fewer reads.

Comment: Oh i thought you were suggesting to have a root collection photos but instead you mean the subcollection

Comment: @AlexChar Well, that a little unclear but within your root firebase, you would have a collection called photos with documents photo_0, photo_1 etc as shown in my answer. So it's kind of a root collection as it would be within the root node but that doesn't really matter as long as the path is static e.g. *firebase_root/photos* could be queried as well as *firebase_root/important_stuff/really_important_stuff/photos* as long as the path is known.

Answer (score 0):

why not just :

list item :[

userB :{...}

userC : {...}

]

userB (and userC) will use the structure you post below, photo1 and photo2 for each item seems redundant

Comment: List item is just an example on what will be displayed on ui. Also my question is how to structure my firestore documents fields/collections etc. I am not sure that my below solution is practical at all.